# derive 2nd order ODE-solution from 1st order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$-\varepsilon v'_\varepsilon + v_\varepsilon^2 = 1\tag{*}$$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ and $v_\varepsilon(0)=0$. Its solution is $$v_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1-e^{2x/\varepsilon}}{1+e^{2x/\varepsilon}}$$

Now I want to derive a solution to the differential equation
$$-\varepsilon u''_\varepsilon + |u_\varepsilon'|^2 = 1$$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ and $u_\varepsilon(0)=0$. Write $v_\varepsilon:=u_\varepsilon'$ and we can derive this ODE from  (*).

Now I want to calculate $u_\varepsilon$ by integration $v_\varepsilon$, but I don't know how to solve the integral $$\int \frac{1-e^{2x/\varepsilon}}{1+e^{2x/\varepsilon}}dx$$

I used wolframalpha to calculate this integral and got $u_\varepsilon(x)=x-\varepsilon\log\left(e^{2x/\varepsilon}+1\right)$, but my paper says the solution is $u_\varepsilon(x)=-\varepsilon\log\left(\frac{\cosh(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})}{\cosh(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})}\right)$.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: One moment: The initial conditions are not consistent. If you assume that $v_\varepsilon(0)=0$, it means that $u_\varepsilon'(0) = 0$, but not $u_\varepsilon(0) = 0$.

Comment: indeed you're right. I have to re-think this I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
x-\varepsilon\log\left(e^{2x/\varepsilon}+1\right)
= x-\varepsilon\log\left(e^{x/\varepsilon} (e^{x/\varepsilon}+e^{-x/\varepsilon})\right)
= x-\varepsilon\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}+\log(2\cosh\frac{x}{\varepsilon})\right)
= -\varepsilon \log2-\varepsilon\log\left(\cosh\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right),
$$
so your expression and the given solution actually agree up to an additive constant. You just have to choose the right constant of integration to fulfil the initial condition.

Comment: this is a good point! Thanks